# Django doesn't show field

Tags: django, forms, field

So, I'm new to django and I am learning
I created a form but django doesn't show it in the page
I am using python 3.9.4
django 3.2

---

this is my code

models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class Commande(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)

forms.py



from django import forms
from .models import Commande


class home_form(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Commande
        fields = ['name']


class RawCmdForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField()
```

views.py

```
from .models import Commande
from django.shortcuts import render
from .forms import home_form, RawCmdForm

# Create your views here.
def home_view(request):
    medocs = Commande.objects.all()
    #print(medocs)
    context = {'medoc' : medocs}
    return render(request, "index.html", context)


def cmd_Form_view(request):
    my_form = RawCmdForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        my_form = RawCmdForm(request.POST)
        if my_form.is_valid():
            print("Good Data")
            Commande.objects.create(**my_form.cleaned_data)
            my_form = RawCmdForm()

    #if request.method == "POST":
    #   new_name= request.POST.get("name")   
    #   Medoc.objects.create(name = new_name)
    context = {"form" : my_form}
    return render(request, "index.html", context)
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Commande</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="color: red"> Mes Manqants</h1>




{% for instance in medoc %}
    <input type="checkbox" id= {{instance.id}} name= {{instance.name}} value= {{instance.name}} >
    <label for= {{medoc.id}} > {{instance.name}} </label><br>

{% endfor %}
</body>


</html>
```

formadd.html

```
{% extends "index.html" %}



{% block content %}

{{ form }}

{% endblock %}
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from cmmd.views import home_view, cmd_Form_view
urlpatterns = [
    path('', home_view),
    path('formadd/', cmd_Form_view),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

I tried with people that had the same problem and I think I did everything as I should but no think changes
so where is the problem

Comment: 1) Your `cmd_Form_view` renders `index.html` while I suppose you wanted to render `formadd.html`. 2) `formadd.html` extends `index.html` and tries to fill a non-existent block `content` (`{% block content %}`)...

Comment: thank you so much I apreciate your help, it works

Comment: what should I do if I want to render the form in the index.html??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your index.html template (inside body) include these. {% block content %} {% endblock %}

```
<body>
...

{% block content %}


{% endblock %}

</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `index.html` file you should have `{% block content %}{% endblock %}` as a placeholder so when it renders `addform.html` and extends `index.html`, django knows where to render the form. More information on template inheritance can be found on: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/language/#template-inheritance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My Commande</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 style="color: red"> Mes Manqants</h1>

    {% for instance in medoc %}
        <input type="checkbox" id= {{instance.id}} name= {{instance.name}} value= {{instance.name}} >
        <label for= {{medoc.id}} > {{instance.name}} </label><br>

    {% endfor %}

    <div id="content">
        {% block content %}{% endblock %}
    </div>
</body>


</html>
```